# Pubsub HTTP POST?

Tags: rest, post, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm working with a service that will forward data to a URL of your choosing via HTTP POST requests.

Is there a simple way to publish to a Pubsub topic with a POST? The service I'm using (Hologram.io's [Advanced Webhook Builder](https://support.hologram.io/hc/en-us/articles/360035696573#advanced-webhook-builder)) can't store any files, so I can't upload a Google Cloud service account JSON key file.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: How do you imagine the authentication flow if you can't provide authentication data?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I'm not sure how to generate the "Authorization: Bearer {}" value in the REST code example here under "Publishing messages", https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher

Comment: Here an example with curl method:     curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" -d @request.json https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/topics/TOPIC_ID:publish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 challenges in your use cases:

- Format
- Authentication

**Format**

You need to customize the webhook to comply with the PubSub format. Some webhoock are enough customizable for that but it's not the case of all. If you can't customize the webhook call as PubSub expect, you need to use an intermediary layer (Cloud Functions or Cloud Run for example)

**Authentication**

Directly to PubSub or with an intermediary layer, the situation is the same: the requester (the webhook) needs to be authenticated and authorized to access to the Google Cloud service.

One of the bad, and possible, practice, is to set `allUsers` authorized to access your resources. Here an example with a PubSub topic

[image]

Don't do that. Even if you increase "your" process security by defining a schema (and thus to reject all the messages that aren't compliant with this schema), letting a resource publicly, and without authentication, accessible on the wild internet is criminal!

In the webhook context (I had this case previously in my company) I recommend you to use a static authentication (a long lived authentication header; not a short lived (1h) as a Google OAuth2 token); an API Key for example. It's not perfect, because in case of API Key leak, the bad actors will be able to use this breach for a long time (rotate as soon as you can your API Keys!), but it's safer than nothing!

I wrote a [pretty old article on this use case (with ESPv2 and Cloud Run)](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-cloud-run-cloud-functions-and-app-engine-with-api-key-73c57bededd1), but the principle, and the configuration, is almost the same on API Gateway, a Google Cloud manage services. In the article, I create a proxy for Cloud Run, Cloud Functions and App Engine, but you can do the same thing with PubSub by setting the correct target URL.

Comment: Thank you for your time and your very thoughtful answer!  I'm going to read your article today :)